# How to define all resolutions under and higher than 1366 in media query?

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I need to define separate CSS files for different screen resolution - one file for width 1366 px and lower, other file for higher. Could you please give me the correct html code?

Answer (score 1):

**For 1366px :**

HTML :

```
<link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet" media="all and (max-width: 1366px)">
```

CSS :

```
@media screen and (max-width: 1366px) {

//codes

}
```

**For other size :**

HTML :

```
<link href="styles2.css" rel="stylesheet" media="all and (min-width: 1366px)">
```

CSS :

```
@media screen and (min-width: 1366px) {

//codes

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could simply define your CSS then use the below for everything below 1366px

```
@media (max-width : 1366 px) {
 /* CSS rules here */
}
```

If you want to specifically define rules for greater than 1366px, you could use:

```
@media (min-width : 1366 px) {
 /* CSS rules here */
}
```